# DateTimeFormat issue

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-conversion

I have a string like below

> 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM

I want it in the yyyy-MM-dd format (in this case 1970-01-01)
My parsing code is

```
var actualDate = DateTime.ParseExact(actualValue,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But I keep getting the error, that the string is not recognized as a valid date time. 
I looked at my variable  **actualValue** and it is of type DateTime, so am thinking that the problem is with the format **MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt** ,What is wrong with this?

Comment: If `actualValue` is a `DateTime`, the code you've got shouldn't even compile, and you wouldn't need to parse it. At the moment your question is very unclear. But basically, you shouldn't be reading the value as a string from the database to start with.

Comment: My apologies, it wasn't read from DB, its a string, as is. I have edited the question.

Comment: Even that doesn't fix the problem of your code not compiling if the type of actualValue is DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be storing or fetching dates as text in the DB.

To your specific issue, however, `MM` and `dd` are the two-digit variety of month and day. Obviously your date text doesn't use the two-digit-only variety, so use `M` and `d`. Also, `HH` is on a 24-hour clock. Using `tt`, which is AM/PM, would imply *not* having a 24 hour clock, so you would want to use `hh` instead.

For more, look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for custom date/time formatting.

Comment: ok, I earlier tried M and d and it didn't work. but using hh instead of HH in addition to M and d worked. good catch on the 12 hr vs 24 hr format!